# Stopping argparse then continue

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

How can I add different argparse at different points in code?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("FirstWord")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.FirstWord)

if args.FirstWord == "hello":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("n")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    print(args.n)
```

When I execute it like this via CMD and let the if statement be true it just prints me **hello** again.
For understanding, I want to argparse something, and if true, I want to print what I argparsed at first and then take another word from me.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`argparse` subparsers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands). Do you have some specific set of subcommands?

Comment: Pretty sure you are not being clear... Did you read about [nargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)?

Comment: You can use `parse_known_args` to parse, well, known args and get back the remaining args to pass to another argument parser. But without more context, this sounds like the intended use case for subparsers.

Comment: What do you mean 'take another word from me'?  Via `input` or the command line?  `argparse` handles the `sys.argv` list, not interactive user input.  You can run several parsers in a script, but they will all parse the same input.

Comment: I want to arparse an "option" as a string, then it should print me this "option" and then I want to argparse another option after the print. Everything via command line! So argparse -> something prints out to command line -> then argparse again.